# Is it possible to get an IEnumerable<Message> from a MessageQueue instance

Tags: linq, msmq

I would like to use Linq over an MSMQ message queue.  As far as I know, I would need to cast the messagequeue as an IEnumerable  Howerver

```
var queryableQ = new MessageQueue(myQueuePath) as IEnumerable<Message>;
```

results in querableQ being null, indicating that a MessageQueue can't be cast as such.

Is there a different approach that could be used to access a MessageQueue using Linq.

(I am aware the GetAllMessages() will return an array which of course is easily queried with Linq, but I would rather not bring the entire queue contents into memory)

Comment: Does this help? http://www.sharepoint4arabs.com/AymanElHattab/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=8 -- or perhaps the white paper linked here? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/motleyqueue/archive/2008/02/09/combining-linq-with-system-messaging.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `Cast()` operator:

```
IEnumberable<Message> queryableQ = new MessageQueue(myQueuePath).Cast<Message>();
```